# Change Request URI spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets

I want to implement a custom filter to change the URI from https://host123/app/users to https://host123/abc/users. In this case, /app and /abc are two separate spring applications running the same tomcat server, (two webapps). So the host remains the same.
From what I have read online, this can be done using a custom filter as both spring applications are in the same servlet container. I have looked up online and created a filter like this:

```
@Component

 public class myFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
 @Override
 protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        String reqURI = request.getRequestURI();

        if (reqURI.startsWith("/app")) {
            CustomServletRequest customRequest = new CustomServletRequest(request);
            String reqURI = request.getRequestURI();
            String newURI = "/abc" + reqURI.substring(4);
            customRequest.setRequestURI(newURI);

            filterChain.doFilter(customRequest, response);

            } else {

                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

            }
    }
 }

final class CustomServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper) {

private String modifiedURI;

public CustomServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    super(request);
}

public void setRequestURI(String uri) {
    this.modifiedURI = uri;
}

@Override
public String getRequestURI() {
    return modifiedURI;
}

@Override
public StringBuffer getRequestURL() {
    StringBuffer url = new StringBuffer();
    url.append(getScheme()).append("://").append(getServerName()).append(modifiedURI);
    return url;
}

}
```

Issue is that I receive 404 for the https:///app/users.. I cannot use redirect as I do not want to show target URI on client side. Has anyone else faced similar issue? Is there anything missing/wrong in the above implementation? I'm fairly new to Spring so any help is much appreciated :)  TIA!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your approach.

Also you can use request forward instead of HttpServletRequestWrapper like below:

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String reqURI = request.getRequestURI();
        if (reqURI.startsWith("/app")) {
            String newURI = "/abc" + reqURI.substring(4);
            request.getRequestDispatcher(newURI).forward(request,response);
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
}
```